# Supporting multiple themes

Tags: codenameone

The "Kitchen Sink" demo shows us how to multiple themes - very cool. The designer allows you, however, to add multiple themes to a single .res file. I added a second theme to my single theme.res file and then it seemed to use the second one as a default, bizarrely. **Is this the correct way to do it?**, or should I only do it the-way-of-the-demo and have multiple .res files?

Comment: You should only do it the way of the demo and have multiple .res files.

Comment: Thanks! I figured they had only done that for clarity with so many themes ... since it allows you to add multiple themes. But when it didn't work as I expected I got suspicious!!

Comment: Mind you, I'm not actually an expert on codenameone.  But if it's using the second one as a default, and the demo works as you expect it to, I think the course of action is apparent.

Comment: I'm always keen to know how something is *supposed* to work - and demos do not always use the official way, for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go both ways as long as the res file doesn't grow to be too big you will be fine.

Just override initTheme and initialize the right theme there.